# Simple Fancybox 2 Keys Options - how to use?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm trying to disable the hotkeys for left and right arrow on Fancybox 2. I've tried using the 'keys' available options but I can't get it to work! Please help:

Here is what I entered in...

```
keys: {
                "next": [13, 32, 34, 39], // enter, space, page down, right arrow, down arrow
                "prev": [8, 33, 37], // backspace, page up, left arrow, up arrow
                "close": [27] // escape key
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to disable navigation you need to set :

```
modal: true,
keys: {
 ....
},
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What if I'm just trying to disable 1 certain hotkey?